# Are these converging or diverging

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am having trouble working out the convergence of these series and was wondering if I could please have some assistance

a) $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sin(e^n)\frac{n}{n^3+1}$

and

b) $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-2)^n}{4^{n+2}+5n}$

I have managed to investigate that b) is convergent through the alternating series test, since it is decreasing and its limit approaches 0. With a) I am just a bit stumped as I thought it was converging at first, but I read somewhere $\sin$ is a diverging function.

Any help would be appriciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please check that your message was not destroyed by my edit.

Answer (score 3):

$$\left|\frac{\sin(\mathrm e^n)\,n}{n^3 + 1}\right|\leqslant\frac1{n^2}
\qquad
\sum_{n\geqslant1}\frac1{n^2}\lt\infty
\qquad
\left|\frac{(-2)^n}{4^{n+2}+5n}\right|\leqslant\frac1{16\cdot2^n}
\qquad
\sum_{n\geqslant1}\frac1{2^n}\lt\infty
$$

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! :)

Answer (score 1):

$$\left| \sin{\left(e^n \right)}\cdot\dfrac{n }{n^3+1}\right| \leqslant{\dfrac{n }{n^3+1}}=\dfrac{1 }{n^2+\tfrac{1}{n}} \leqslant {\dfrac{1 }{n^2}},\\
\left|\dfrac{(-2)^n}{4^{n+2}+5n}\right|=\dfrac{\left|(-1)^n\right|}{2^{2n+4-n}+\tfrac{5n}{2^n}}=\dfrac{1}{2^{n+4}+\tfrac{5n}{2^n}}\lt{\dfrac{1}{2^{n+4}}}.$$

Comment: For the second line, the first equality is not true : you have forgotten to divide $5n$ by $2^n$... (but it does not change the logic of this reasoning!)

Comment: Really, thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your answers - with the first line, are you suggesting that we do not need to consider the fact that sin(e^n) diverges/is undefined?

Comment: $\sin(e^n)$ anyhow is bounded: $|\sin(e^n)|\leqslant{1}$